# How can I pass different command line arguments to a Task in aws every time I run it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

### What I want to accomplish

I want have a computationally heavy python function that:

1. takes a file from an S3 bucket
2. transforms it
3. then saves a new file to the S3 bucket

I have done functions like these as lambda functions before, but this one is very computationally heavy and takes a long time, so I decided it would be better to package it in a container, put it on ECS and run it through Fargate. (Forgive my use of these terms if I am doing it incorrectly, I haven't wrapped my head around these concepts yet)

#### ... Practically:

So I want to be able to run the Task that has that image of my docker container like I run my container locally, **passing arguments to it every time I run it**, and these arguments **are different** for every run:

Run 1:

```bash
docker run python-image input_file_path_1 output_file_path_1
```

Run 2:

```bash
docker run python-image input_file_path_2 output_file_path_2
```

From what I understand, I can change the **task definition** to include passing arguments to the script, which seems like they are "hardcoded" into the task **definition**, meaning they cannot be changed for **every run**.

### Question?

So in essence, my question is how do I run this task, either from the cli or the user interface or a lambda function, where I would be able to pass arguments dynamically, every time I run the Task?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [ECS RunTask API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html), you'll see an `overrides` parameter. Inside that `overrides` parameter you can override things such as the container environment variables, and the `command`. In your instance it sounds most appropriate to pass an override of the `command` each time you call RunTask.

You mentioned both the CLI and AWS Lambda. For the CLI you can see the documentation [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html). You didn't mention what programming language you are using for AWS Lambda, but all the AWS SDKs have an ECS RunTask you can lookup in their respective documentation to see how to pass in an override.

Comment: I don't want to override the whole command. I want to just give it parameters it is already expecting. So for example 3 parameters specifically. My idea was that parameters would be given in some JSON object with key-value pairs, with keys being the expected parameter name and the value being the value of that (or even just 3 strings like you would do to a program that runs on the terminal). Is this possible?

Comment: Also, I am using python on AWS lambda, so the boto3 library to interact with the Task.

Comment: There's no "partial override" option. You have to override the whole command. It's really not a big deal.